# Is there a way to make an extension from a google sheet cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I don't really know how to describe this, but let say on one cell from google sheets you are able to click on it and a list of additional cells pop up (not related to the other cells), and this new created cell can be shortened into one cell, or expanded into multiple for convenience.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, its hard for me to explain. It's like can I make a cell expand into many cells which can ultimately be shrunk down to that one original cell. Like a pop up drop list  of sorts

Comment: Sounds like you are describing a web app not a spreadsheet.  The spreadsheet could be the source/destination of data but the dynamic functionality you are describing (unless it is drop menus) is unknown to me.  why don't you describe why you are trying to do that and maybe we can help further.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a _possible solution to a problem_ rather than the _problem_. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Answer (score 0):

You can create column groups that expand and collapse when you click `+` and `-` buttons, and ditto for rows. There is no way expand or collapse a single cell.

See [Group or ungroup rows or columns](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9060449?hl=en#zippy=%2Cgroup-or-ungroup-rows-or-columns).